# How do I enable different 'POST' page types in SpringMVC depending on which button a user presses?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, http-post

I've probably worded my question poorly, so here's some code.

In my controller, I have this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateGoal(@Valid @ModelAttribute("goal") Goal goal, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("result has errors: " + result.hasErrors());

    System.out.println("Goal set: " + goal.getMinutes());

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addGoal";
    } else {
        goalService.save(goal);
    }

    return "redirect:index.jsp";
}
```

This says (as far as I understand it), if a user sends an HTTP `POST` request to the `addGoal.jsp` page: create an instance of the Goal object, and redirect them to `index.jsp`.

My question is, how do I have multiple POST methods for a given page? EG 2 buttons - 1 button does the above `POST` method, and a different button on the page does a different `POST` method.

Thanks in advance, sorry if I'm explaining it poorly, still learning!

Comment: Define a separate method with different POST url !

Comment: Not sure I understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This says (as far as I understand it), if a user sends an HTTP POST request to the addGoal.jsp page
```

Not quite, the user sends the POST to this method (`addGoal`) which has been mapped by Spring, it returns to either (probably) WEB-INF/jsp/addGoal.jsp or /index.jsp

You can have multiple forms on a jsp, each sending to a different method if you define different mappings for each one, examples:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//addGoal code
@RequestMapping(value = "addFoul", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//addFoul code
@RequestMapping(value = "addSelfGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//addSelfGoal code
```

and have them all return to `addGoal`, though you would probably want to use a more general name at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - my question for additional clarification is **how do I specify which method gets called**? Is it some HTML a:href property?

Like say I have all 3 of those methods, and 3 buttons labeled "Add Goal", "Add Foul", "Add Self Goal". How do I link those buttons to the specific methods that correlate to them?

Comment: If you're using html `<form action='yourRequestMapping'...`, if Spring `<form:form modelAttribute='yourModel'...` and Spring will fill in the action

Comment: Another option we use is to use a form property to determine the right method.  We call ours "actionMethod", and it's just a hidden input type that we set.  In the Spring mapping we do something like this: @RequestMapping(params = "actionMethod=preivew")